# Apply for US passport for my child; other parent is abroad

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

My daughter was just born in California while I was on a visit to the US.

My husband is in Turkey and cannot travel to the US to apply for our child's application for a US passport.

How can he declare his consent on DS-3053 document and sign it at a certified notary without being here?

Can he sign DS-3053 with a notary outside the United States?

Answer (score 3):

The US [embassies](http://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/judicial/authentication-of-documents/notarial-and-authentication-services-consular-officers.html) and consulates in Turkey will provide notary service. It is also possible to use a local notary, but then further paperwork is required. (Same link.)